# Drill bit coming loose on a basic rotary/impact/hammer drill

Tags: drill

I just received this 21V 350 in-lb impact drill [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B088JYH44C/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088JYH44C)

[image]

The 350 in-lb torque rating seemed kinda decent so honestly I expected better results than I am getting. I am wondering is it

- "user error" (my first impact drill here)
- expected limitations of this modest tool?
- different bit extender needed

The tests I did:

With a two inch thick oak board:

- drive a screw as deep as I can
- drill out a 3/8 inch hole with a spade bit

In both cases they just gave up at one inch depth.  Bits would come loose and wobble, and no further progress could be made.

As far as tightening/locking the bit:  I watched a few youtube's and they talked about higher end dewalt/milwaukee etc that have locking mechanisms.  This tool does not have a similar mechanism.  Even so the instructions mention

> The bit is secure when the chuck makes a ratcheting sound and the sleeve can not be rotated any further".

I did not hear any ratcheting sound even though the fit is tight (before drilling).

Based on a comment I will make the implicit goals here explicit:

"What needs to be done (if possible at all) to achieve"

```
* two inches of screw fastening in oak
* two inches of 3/8 inch spade boring in oak
```

The answers may be some combination of:

- drilling type settings: classic vs impact vs hammer (latter not likely..)
- speed settings:  1 (low speed higher torque)  2 (high speed lower torque)
- ratcheting settings:   1 to 25

Comment: How do you tighten it? Hold the chuck and run the drill, or hold both bits and twist? If it's not ratcheting, you're either not tightening properly, or the chuck is faulty, I'd say.

Comment: The latter: i'm twisting the chuck not running the drill.  I'd be happy to learn I'm doing it incorrectly:but would mention they are tight even just on hand tightening.

Comment: Oak is a pretty hard wood, generally, you'd drill a pilot hole before running a screw through it. Also, there's no guarantee that the spade bit is all that super sharp. Those could both be problems. Also, what do you mean by "they just gave up at one inch depth"? Did the drill stop operating? Were the bits slipping in the chuck? I like the quick-change bits with the flats, but if you're using them in a 3-jaw chuck like this, you need to make sure the jaws are sitting on the flats, not the corners or they'll pop out when the going gets tough.

Comment: It appears that the chuck has a clutch - do you have it on its highest setting? If not, the clutch will slip when the resistance gets too high because that's what it's supposed to do. It should have a "drill" setting that locks out the clutch preventing it from slipping at all. Looking at the pics at Amazon, those spade bits don't look to be the highest quality piece of kit... Also, it claims a "No-load speed 19000-23000rpm" - that's router territory. No drill/driver in it's right mind would _ever_ spin that fast. Either there's a typo with extra zeros, or all their claims are... sketchy...

Comment: "Just gave up" means the bits would come loose and start wobbling.  The speed is definitely having an extra zero on it. I have tried both the 1 (more torque) and 2 (more speed/rpm) settings.   There does not appear to be a "highest" setting as in some drills but just  1 to 25. I have tried it at all levels but especially the 25.  wrt the spade bit: yea it does seem kinda lame.

Comment: @FreeMan btw I have tried every combination of setting as well ;)  drill/impact/hammer on 1/2 and on 1 to 25.

Comment: I don't know what your body is like physically but I know some people (for example my mum) struggle massively with keyless chucks simply because they lack the grip strength to propertly tighten/loosen them.

Comment: @PeterGreen  Few mins ago got the high speed drill with a spade bit going down full depth of the bit (2+ inches) . I'm guessing the driver for screws is coming out due to an inadequate bit for the depth. Getting a six inch driver tonight and let's see.  At this point I do not suspect locking/lack thereof to be the issue.

Comment: You should get someone stronger than you to tighten the chuck and test again to see if it's a grip strength issue.  If it is, you can add sandpaper grip tape to the chuck to improve your grip.  If you do, do not tighten the chuck by running the drill, which you may not have the grip strength for anyway.

Comment: @KH  Turns out to be unlikely to be a grip strength issue or even locking issue at all - see my answer below.

Comment: @StephenBoesch You should be able to grip round bits well enough to max out the torque of the drill on a 1/4" or 3/8" round shank bit, so you may still have chuck issues.  Some brands have interchangeable chucks.  I can tighten my Milwaukee chucks tight enough by hand to leave a mark in a drill bit.  I do occasionally spin a bit out, but when I do the marks on the shaft indicate it was tight enough, the bit shaft just wasn't strong enough.

Comment: @KH I will put photos of the old and new bits. The old bit is attached via a supplied adapater that allowed it to vibrate/wobble a bit _even without a load_ . That is what was causing the bit to fall out. The _makita_ adapter holds it firm and no more issues there.

Comment: If your drill really is combo drill/impact/hammer and not drill/hammer, be sure to use the impact mode with impact rated bits.  Regular ones can be ruined fairly quickly.  If the hex part of a quick change bit was slipping, that's just horrible manufacture.  If the tip of the bit is slipping, be aware there are many very similar screw head types as well as the dimensional concerns of manufacturing.

Comment: We had another treatment of drills question today and I just came back to add that you should only use extension/ quick change bits in low torque applications or when actually necessary.  The chuck of your drill has a superior, more aligned grip and you can prematurely wear out even decent quality bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that if you've cranked the chuck down as tight as it goes and the bits still slip, especially hex-shank bits with the chuck jaws on the flats of the shanks,  then either there's a problem with the drill, or it's just simply not up to the task of drilling through oak.

Oak is a reasonably hard, dense wood (about 1290-1360 on the Janka scale).It is not, by any means, the hardest stuff out there, though, but it's around twice as hard as SPF (about 650-700 on the Janka), so an off-brand, more entry level tool may not be exactly the right one for that job.

[Janka scale](https://www.bellforestproducts.com/info/janka-hardness/) and definition. No affiliation, just the first place with a nice listing & definition.

Comment: Yea Oak is pretty nice thus I thought a good test (pine would seem too easy).  I did expect better than what I got.  I'll be trying out additional extensions/tips in the coming days: I suspect more can be had from this tool.

Answer (score 1):

You bought inexpensive equipment and you are getting inexpensive performance .

Comment: Yea i'm needing to supplement here. The bits provided in particular are garbage. Let's see what happens with the magnetic 6" extension.

Comment: That is also my guess. I also got one of those knock off brands and I would qualify it as a disposable toy

Answer (score 0):

If the drill bits are slipping and are the round type, maybe use the type made for 'quick attach' which kind of have a bolt looking type end...thats all I could think of...you are saying the drill bit is not holding?

Comment: Yea the bits just come loose. Will add some detail above on tightening/locking the bit

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer board, not a general discussion forum. As such, we expect answers to the question to be posted in the box labeled "Answer". Since this doesn't seem to answer the question, would you please [edit] it into an answer? If you'll stick around, you'll quickly earn enough rep to make a comment on someone else's Q or A, which is what this is as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

I was just now able to get a 1/2 inch hole down two inches+ with the spade bit. It was the classic drill setting on highest speed.  It required a number of iterations: go down a piece then come back out to let the shavings out and give the bit a chance to cool a moment. Rinse cleanse repeat.

For driving the screw - which the impact driver is better suited - I presently lack the correct bit. A couple of good candidates are arriving by tomorrow and I will update here.

**Update**  The six inch *Makita* magnetic bit holder arrived and there is no more issues with slippage/bits coming out when fastening the screw. It is still not able to go more than about an inch but trying to screw into Oak without predrilling is probably a tall order in any case.

Comment: *For driving the screw - which the impact driver is better suited* - Actually, when screwing into wood the regular drill mode should be just fine. The impact mode is more for masonry - brick, concrete, etc.

Comment: @StephenBoesch this appears to be a comment, not an answer ... please delete it if it does not answer your question

Comment: @jsotola This is answering the question: ie _can_ the goal be achieved (at least partially) and _how_ can it be achieved ( classical drill for spade and pending for fastener/screw).  I will be adding further detail when the additional bit arrives

Comment: @StephenBoesch if you read your own post, then you will see that there are no actual questions ... only a description of what you are wondering about ... there is nothing about `can goal be achieved?` or `how can goal be achieved?`

Comment: True that it is not explicitly mentioned.  It is implicit  and imo not difficult to infer:  how to get the two inches of screw fastening and spade bit drilling.

Comment: @jsotola  The goals were now explicitly added to the question.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Yes i'm now learning that normal drill mode is working better for the screw into wood.